# docker container : service exits immediately

Tags: docker, service, containers, exit

I run a container in the background

```
docker run -d -e SERVER_ADDR=127.0.0.1 --name resource agent:1.0
```

but it exited immediately.

**DOCKERFILE**

```
FROM centos:latest
MAINTAINER Simon <khlyum@innerbus.com>

RUN yum -y update; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install systemd; yum clean all;

RUN mkdir -p /cloud/config
RUN mkdir -p /cloud/log

WORKDIR /cloud

COPY sm_agent_resource sm_agent_resource
COPY config/agent.conf config/agent.conf
COPY config/log.xml config/log.xml
COPY cloud-resource cloud-resource
COPY certificate.pem certificate.pem
COPY client.crt client.crt
COPY client.key client.key

CMD /cloud/cloud-resource
```

**cloud-resource**

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 234 90 90

NAME=agent_resource    
AGENT_HOME=/cloud

echo "Agent Config Setting"
sed -i '3i\  "agent_server_ip":"'${SERVER_ADDR}'",' config/agent.conf

echo "Start Cloud Agent_Resource"
nohup /cloud/sm_agent_resource 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
#nohup /cloud/sm_agent_resource >>log/agent.log 2>&1 (<==I try it also.)
```

When I connected to the docker by /bin/bash and run the cloud-resource, process was running.

```
run -d -it -e SERVER_ADDR=127.0.0.1 --name resource1 agent:1.0 --entrypoint /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 2):

A docker container will be stopped as soon as its root process is finished.

You are defining the root process with

```
CMD /cloud/cloud-resource
```

Inside the docker container it will be executed and as soon as the execution finishes the container will be stopped. As the last command of `cloud-resource` is a `nohup` with an `&` at the end you are moving the command to the background. And after that command the script ends and so does the root process of the container.

The fact that

```
docker run -d -it -e SERVER_ADDR=127.0.0.1 --name resource1 agent:1.0 --entrypoint /bin/bash
```

keeps running is that you are overwriting the root process with `entrypoint /bin/bash`. `-i` tells docker additionally to keep STDIN open even if not attached. So your bash is active - even though detached.

Try modifying your script to not use `nohup` and `&`

Comment: you should advise the OP to remove the `nohup` command from it cloud-resource script

Comment: I didn't recognize that the content of cloud-resource was described in the question and updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for response.
so how do I set script for sm_agent_resource not dying??

Comment: I dont know what exactly `sm_agent_resource` does, but can't you just remove the nohup so the command won't be detached? Like `./cloud/sm_agent_resource` instead of `nohup /cloud/sm_agent_resource 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &` (I don't know what `1>/dev/null 2>&1` does). A possible dirty workaround would be to add a `tail -f /dev/null` or something that lasts endless after your `nohup` command inside of cloud-resource script. But then your root process is depending / based on the tail command instead of the sm_agent_resource command.

Comment: Removing `nohup`should do the trick: with `nohup`, your main process terminates immediately (causing the container to stop), you should also remove `1>/dev/null 2>&1` which causes standard and error output to be lost (redirected in `/dev/null` - if you do not specify anything, the standard output will be read by Docker and visible with `docker logs`